# Instantiate StreamExecutionEnvironment in Scala Shell

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I start the scala shell. It automatically creates an ExecutionEnvironment from the type org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment

However, I would like to use a streaming environment.

```
val senv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
```

leads to an exception as an ExecutionEnvironement can only be instantiated once.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, `StreamExecutionEnvironment` is not supported in Flink Scala shell. There is a pull request (https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/1412) addressing this issue. Maybe you can use `StreamExecutionEnvironment` in next release.

Comment: The pull request has been merged. You may try out the Scala Shell with streaming in the latest Apache Flink snapshot build.